# Reversing Linked List in C

Tags: c, oclint

I've been working on a code to reverse a linked list, but I only seem to be getting the first element printed out in my list. Here is my function:

```
void reverseSqueue(Squeue squeue) {
    if (squeue -> first == NULL || squeue -> last == NULL){
        return;
    }
    Node* temp = NULL;
    Node* curr = squeue -> first;
    squeue -> first = squeue -> last;
    squeue -> last = curr;

    /*if (squeue -> first != squeue -> last){
      curr = curr -> next;
    }

    printf("%s\n", curr -> next -> value);
    printf("%s\n", curr -> value);
    printf("%s\n", curr -> prev -> value);
    printf("______________\n");
    printf("%s\n", squeue -> first -> value);
    Node* nde = squeue -> first;
    while (nde != NULL){
        printf("%s\n", nde -> value);
    nde = nde -> prev;
    }*/
    while (curr != NULL){
    /*if (curr != squeue -> first || curr != squeue -> last){
        if (curr -> next == squeue -> last){
            curr = NULL;
        }else{*/
        temp = curr;
        curr -> next = curr;
        curr = temp;
        curr = curr -> prev;
      //}
    //}else{
    //curr = NULL;
    //}
    }
}
```

I apologize for the messy code, I tried running multiple tests and commented them out here; I had code before that worked fine but gave a garbage value warning in OClint, so I tried fixing them and now my code just doesn't seem to work anymore. If nothing else works, I can just go back to my original code. Any input is much appreciated!

```
struct node {
  char *value;
  struct node *next;
  struct node *prev;
};
typedef struct node Node;

struct squeue {
   struct node* first;
   struct node* last;
};
typedef struct squeue * Squeue;
```

Comment: Can you give the definition for Node and Squeue?

Comment: Yep! Added it as an edit

Comment: `curr -> next = curr;` That doesn't look right.

Comment: I'm trying to reverse squeue, and why not? It seemed to work perfectly fine before I tried to address a memory issue

Comment: Error is in `Node* curr = squeue -> first;` You didn't create a node curr

Comment: FWIW, linked lists tend to be much slower than an array you malloc and realloc, because of memory latency.

Comment: @William you don't want to reverse squeue because it cannot store data! What will you do reversing "Squeue" which doesn't have data to be reversed in the first place

Comment: Can you show errors you are getting?

Comment: Style note: the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly and should not be written with spaces around them in orthodox C style.  Putting spaces around them marks the code as "written by a tyro (newbie)".

Comment: Sorry about that! I've figured out the code by tracing back my steps, I realized I mixed myself up in the while loop. Thank you all for helping though!

Answer (score 0):

With curr->next = curr you are saying that the next node of the current node is the current node, that is, current node points to itself as it's next node.

```c
Node *first = squeue->last; 
squeue->last = squeue->first; // the last node is now the first
squeue->first = first; // squeue->first = original order squeue->last

Node *curr = first; 
while (curr != NULL) { // loop begins with the original order last node,
                       // but new order first node

    // curr->next, curr->prev = curr->prev, curr->next
    Node *prev = curr->prev; // saves the curr's prev
    curr->prev = curr->next; // modifies curr's prev, now pointing to curr's next
    curr->next = prev; // curr's next now points to it's original prev

    curr = curr->next; // the next curr is the original order curr's prev,
                       // but the now order curr's next
}
```